# .NET Chart Control Ignores LabelAutoFitStyle When Chart Size Specified

Tags: .net, powershell, charts

I'm trying to generate a line chart with .NET 4 in-built chart control.
I want to have the X axis labels on an angle *and* I want to have my chart a specific size.

If specify the width/height of the chart, the LabelAutoFitStyle is ignored. I've also tried using .Angle property etc on the label, and they only work if I don't specify the width & height of the chart.

But if I don't specify the width & height of the chart, the data is all cramped into a very tiny chart.

Is there a way to use LabelAutoFitStyle *and* ensure the chart is larger size, preferably a specific size.

I've tried using $chart.MinimumSize and $chart.Size as well, but they don't seem to impact the chart output.

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization")

ForEach ($url in $urlList)
{
    $chart = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
    #$chart.Width = 1024
    #$chart.Height = 690

    $chart.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
    $chart.Titles.Add("$url load time (ms)")
    $chart.Titles[0].Alignment ="topLeft"
    $chart.AutoSize = $true
    $chartArea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
    $chartArea.name = "ChartArea1"
    $chartArea.AxisY.Title = "Load Time (ms)"
    $chartArea.AxisX.Title = "Time"
    $chartArea.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = $true
    $chartArea.AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LabelAutoFitStyles]::LabelsAngleStep90

    $chartArea.Axisx.LabelStyle.Enabled = $true 
    $chart.ChartAreas.Add($chartArea)
    $colorIndex = 0

    ForEach ($pac in $pacList)
    {
        $chart.Series.Add($pac)
        $chart.Series[$pac].ChartType = "Line"
        $chart.Series[$pac].BorderWidth = $borderWidth
        $chart.Series[$pac].IsVisibleInLegend = $true
        $chart.Series[$pac].ChartArea = "ChartArea1"
        $chart.Series[$pac].Color = $colorList[$colorindex]
        $colorindex++

    }
    $urlData = $data | Where-Object { $_.URL -eq $url }
    ForEach ($row in $urlData)
    {
        $chart.Series[$row.'PAC FILE'].Points.AddXY( $row.TIME, $row.'Page Load Time 2 (ms)')
    }

    $chartFilename = (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath (Fix-Filename $url)) + ".png"
    $chart.SaveImage($chartFilename,"png")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use the following lines:

```
$chartarea.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = $false
$chartarea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90
```

where I set **IsLabelAutoFit** explicitely to **$false**.
I can set width and hight to what ever I like and the labels are angled 90 degrees.

```
$chart.Width = 1024
$chart.Height = 690
```